# "ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente" en subconsulta

Tags: .net, oracle

Tengo un back en .NET y lo tengo de esta forma:

```cs
[HttpGet("ObtenerAfiliados")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerAfiliados() {
    string SQLQuery = "SELECT  " +
        "  a.NU_IDAFILIADO_AFIL, " +
        "  a.TX_UUID, " +
        "  a.TX_CORREOUNAL_AFIL, " +
        "  a.TX_CORREOALTER_AFIL, " +
        "  a.TX_IDENTIFICACION_AFIL, " +
        "  a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL, " +
        "  TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL) / 12) AS EDAD, " +
        "  TRUNC(MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL), 12)) AS MESES_RESTANTES, " +
        "  TRUNC(MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL), 1) * 30.44) AS DIAS_RESTANTES " +
        "FROM HIMSCAP.\"Afiliados\" AS a " +
        "WHERE TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL) / 12) = 17 " +
        "  AND TRUNC(MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL), 12)) = 0 " +
        "  AND TRUNC(MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 1), a.FE_FECHANACIMIENTO_AFIL), 1) * 30.44) < 31 " +
        "  AND a.TX_UUID NOT IN ( " +
        "    SELECT DISTINCT s.TX_UUID " +
        "    FROM HIMSCAP.segnotificaciones AS s     " +
        "    WHERE s.TX_UUID IS NOT NULL " +
        "  ) ";


    try
    {
        using (var conexion = _context.Database.GetDbConnection())
        using (var cmd = conexion.CreateCommand())
        {
            DataTable tablaInfo = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(SQLQuery, (OracleConnection)conexion);

            await conexion.OpenAsync();
            OracleTransaction transaccion = (OracleTransaction)conexion.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
            try
            {
                cmd.Transaction = transaccion;
                cmd.CommandText = SQLQuery;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
                transaccion.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transaccion.Rollback();
                //_errorModel.error = true;
                //_errorModel.cuerpo.Add(e.Message);
                return BadRequest(e);
            }
            oracleDataAdapter.Fill(tablaInfo);
            await conexion.CloseAsync();

            //_errorModel.error = false;
            //_errorModel.cuerpo.Add("Consulta válida.");
            return Ok(tablaInfo.AsDataView());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e);
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que al ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente'

pero si a la sentencia le quito esta parte:

```
AND a.TX_UUID NOT IN ( " +
                "    SELECT DISTINCT s.TX_UUID " +
                "    FROM HIMSCAP.segnotificaciones AS s     " +
                "    WHERE s.TX_UUID IS NOT NULL " +
                "  )
```

funciona de maravilla. Ya he ensayado cambiando a un join en vez de una subconsulta con SELECT y me sale el mismo error.

¿O un back en .NET no permite subconsultas?

Comment: es normal que dentro de un query existan tantos espacios???

Comment: que pasa si tienes una subconsulta NOT IN (sub) y sub contiene NULL???

Comment: la subconsulta es para traerme aquellas personas que no se encuentran en esa segunda tabla, el problema es que si lo ejecuto en el ORACLE si funciona bien

Comment: ¿Quitaste el `AS` en `FROM HIMSCAP.segnotificaciones AS s`? No olvides mencionar con qué versión de Oracle estás trabajando. Y por cierto, si en realidad estás trabajando con ASP.NET o .NET, reemplaza la etiqueta de tu pregunta por la que realmente corresponda.

Answer (score 1):

Al revisar el [diagrama de sintaxis](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126854) de `SELECT` (donde dice *`select_list::=`*), o la [descripción del mismo diagrama](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/img_text/select_list.html):

```sql
{ *
| { query_name.*
  | [ schema. ] { table | view | materialized view } .*
  | t_alias.*
  | expr [ [ AS ] c_alias ]
  }
    [, { query_name.*
       | [ schema. ] { table | view | materialized view } .*
       | t_alias.*
       | expr [ [ AS ] c_alias ]
       }
    ]...
}
```

se puede ver que entre *t_alias* (*table alias*, *alias de tabla*) y *c_alias* (*column alias*, *alias de columna*) hay una sutil diferencia: a *c_alias*, opcionalmente, ***puede*** precederle la palabra clave `AS`, sin embargo en el caso de *t_alias*, si se mira en el ejemplo presente en [*Using Correlated Subqueries: Examples*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2066912):

```sql
SELECT select_list 
    FROM table1 t_alias1 
    WHERE expr operator 
        (SELECT column_list 
            FROM table2 t_alias2 
            WHERE t_alias1.column 
               operator t_alias2.column); 

UPDATE table1 t_alias1 
    SET column = 
        (SELECT expr 
            FROM table2 t_alias2 
            WHERE t_alias1.column = t_alias2.column); 

DELETE FROM table1 t_alias1 
    WHERE column operator 
        (SELECT expr 
            FROM table2 t_alias2 
            WHERE t_alias1.column = t_alias2.column);
```

En ningún momento aparece la palabra clave `AS`.

---

Todo lo anterior es para explicar que: `AS` solo se utiliza (opcionalmente) para alias de columnas.
Los alias de tablas no llevan `AS`: es sintaxis inválida.

<sub>En los enlaces se muestra la documentación según la versión 12.2 de Oracle, pero para las versiones 19 y 23 es lo mismo.</sub>